# scanf adds a new line character to my string automatically

Tags: c, scanf, whitespace, c-strings, conversion-specifier

I'm trying to solve a basic problem where I have to print a string a output I complete my code and submitted it for test case it prints the correct output but it includes a newline character at the beginning of the output string, due to this the test case fails.

the **Input** is in the form of:

```
Arun:40:51:60
roger:49:51:62
steve:80:71:60
```

The **output** should be the name of the student with the highest score:
**steve**

but my program outputs:
"
steve"

this is my **program**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int val=0,topMark=0;
    char topStudent[101];
    scanf("%d",&val);
    for(int i=0;i<val;i++)
    {
        char arr[101]; 
        int m1,m2,m3;
        scanf("%[^:]:%d:%d:%d",arr,&m1,&m2,&m3);
        if(topMark<(m1+m2+m3))
        {
            topMark=m1+m2+m3;
            strcpy(topStudent,arr);
        }
    }
    puts(topStudent[i]);   
}
```

I tried using both **printf** and **puts** functions, but it still prints a new line.

I'm expecting a way to get the input without the newline character at the beginning of the string or printing the string without the newline character at the beginning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: Note that there are just three conversion specifiers that do not skip white space, and they are `%c`, `%n` and `%[…]` (scan sets).  Include a space at the start of the format string: `" %[^:]…"`.  If you printed all the student information, you'd find that `Arun` did not have a newline at the start, but both `steve` and `roger` do.

Comment: @Vignesh Magalingam,  Do not use `scanf("%[^:]...` without a _width_.  In this case use `scanf(" %100[^:]` and check the return value of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a leading space in the format string as for example

```
scanf(" %[^:]:%d:%d:%d",arr,&m1,&m2,&m3);
      ^^^
```

It allows to skip white space characters including the new line character `'\n'` stored in the input buffer after a preceding call of `scanf`.

From the C 23 Standard (7.23.6.2 The fscanf function)

> 5 A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by
> reading input up to the first nonwhite-space character (which remains
> unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never
> fails.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    char s[N];

    printf( "Enter a string (no more than %d symbols): ", N - 1 );
    scanf( "%9[^\n]", s );

    printf( "s = \"%s\"\n", s );

    printf( "ENter a string (no more than %d symbols): ", N - 1 );
    scanf( " %9[^\n]", s );

    printf( "s = \"%s\"\n", s );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a string (no more than 9 symbols):      A
s = "     A"
Enter a string (no more than 9 symbols):      B
s = "B"
```